# Recursively subtracting a second value from a first while keeping count then return the count

Tags: python, loops, sum

I am attempting to write recursive functions in python that calculate div and mod.
div takes two integers as input and keeps on subtracting the second from the first until the
first number becomes less than the second number. The function keeps a track of how many
times the second number is subtracted from the first and returns that number as the answer.
mod also takes two integers as input and keeps on subtracting the second from the first
until the first number becomes less than the second number. When the first number
becomes less than the second, the value of the first number is the answer.

```
def div ():
    n=0
    m=0
    count=0
    n=input("Enter first Integer:")
    m=input("Enter second Integer:")
if n<m:
    return 0
else:
n= int(n)-int(m)
count=count+1
    print (count)
    n+=1
```

Comment: your code has wrong indentations - so it is useless and th this is only waste of time.

Comment: maybe first use `input()` and convert string to `int()` and later run recursive function with all values as parameters - `subtrack(n, m)`. And don't forget to do `return count` and `count = subtrack(n-m, m) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could get all values and convert to `int()` and later you could run recursive function with these values as arguments

```
def subtrack(n, m):
    if n < m:
       return 0

    count = subtrack(n-m, m) + 1
    
    return count

# --- main ---

n = int(input("Enter first Integer:"))
m = int(input("Enter second Integer:"))

count = subtrack(n, m) 

print(count)
``
```